# How to search RealmList field of RealmObj

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a realm object like:

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {

private String fullName;
private RealmList<PhoneNumberObj> phoneNumbers;}
```

Where the class PhoneNumberObj looks like:

```
public class PhoneNumberObj extends RealmObject {

private String phoneNumber;
private String type;
}
```

Is it possible to use a realm query to find a person with a specific phoneNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, using a link query

```
RealmResults<Person> persons = realm.where(Person.class)
                                   .equalTo("phoneNumbers.phoneNumber", phoneNumber)
                                   .findAllAsync();
```